# Cant add data to file

Tags: ruby

```
file_1 = File.open('Data_family.txt', 'r')
user1 = go
while user1 != "stop"
    print "whould you like to create: "
    user1 = gets.chomp
    print "what is your relation: "
    relation = gets.chomp
    file_1.syswrite "this is your " + relation
    file_1.syswrite "\n"
end
file_1.close
```

am am confused as to why by block does not run. I whould like to create a family tree data base yet it will not allow me to add data to the file i opened

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It will help if you also put the error message you get. My guess is that on the second line, `user1 = go` should be within quotes: `user1 = "go"`.

Comment: Why does it not allow me to get inside the loop

Comment: You can't write data to a file you opened in "read-only" mode. "r" means "read-only".

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/eval ruby 

File.open('Data_family.txt', 'w') do |file_1|
  loop do
    print "Who would you like to create: "
    user1 = gets.chomp
    break if user1 == "stop"
    print "what is your relation: "
    relation = gets.chomp
    file_1.puts "this is your " + relation
  end
end #File autocloses at the end of the block
```